# JavaScript is not working in webView loaded from asset

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I am trying to load `offline version of python documentation` into an `webview` from `asset`folder. The offline docs work perfectly in my pc web browser in offline but not working properly in `webview` (something like `jquery is missing`).

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/python/index.html");
    }

}
```

And this error message is shown when I tried to load the home page or navigate to any page.

```
09-24 01:03:02.789: E/Web Console(479): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ at file:///android_asset/python/index.html:164
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Not sure but usually thi smust work
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, This won't work as I intended to achieve like an phonegap app. I am working in Android plaform with Java. The webpages are now sohwig normally as like other android app.